# Python package not installing submodules

Tags: python, package

I have created a package with the following structure in the dev branch (not merging to main until I verify the package installs correctly):

```
mypackage
|
|-- __init__.py
|-- setup.py
|-- requirements.txt
|-- module.py
|-- subpackage_one
    |
    |-- __init__.py
    |-- module_ab.py
        |-- class_aba
        |-- class_abb
    |-- module_ac.py
        |-- function_aca

|-- subpackage_two
    |
    |-- __init__.py
    |-- module_ba.py
        |-- function_baa
```

Additional information:

- The `__init__.py` files at root and in `subpackage__two` are both empty
- The `__init__.py` file in `subpackage_one` contains some additional initialization in the form of `from mypackage.subpackage_one.module_xx import class_xxx` (or `function_xxx`)
- I am installing the package via `pip install git+https://github.com/organization/repo.git@dev`
- If I am in the root directory of the package, I can import the submodules as expected
- The setup.py file is:

```
import setuptools

with open("README.md", "r", encoding="utf-8") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()

setuptools.setup(
    name='mypackage',
    version='0.0.2',
    author='author1, author2',
    author_email='author1_email, author2_email',
    description='My Package',
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    url='https://github.com/organization/repo',
    packages=['mypackage'],
    install_requires=['requests'],
)
```

- When I run the following snippet:

```
import pkgutil
for i in pkgutil.iter_modules(mypackage.__path__):
    print(i)
```

I see:

```
ModuleInfo(module_finder=FileFinder('/path/to/package/mypackage'), name='module', ispkg=False)
```

And indeed, the subpackages are not in the mypackage folder.

How can I get the subpackages to install along with the package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue might be the `packages` parameter. It needs to be supplied with every module or 'package'.

`setuptools` has a nice function to find them, use it like this: `packages=setuptools.find_namespace_packages(),`

Comment: Ok that mostly worked. It downloads the subpackage folder and associated modules. I failed to mention (didn't think it was relevant) that I have some json files inside `subpackage_two` that aren't showing up now. Any suggestions there? Thanks

Comment: Never mind I found the answer here regarding the missing data
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30164073/python-setup-py-include-json-files-in-the-egg