# Submodules in python package are not imported

Tags: python, installation, pip

I would like to install my own package for development, I have done this several times without issue, but now, although I add my `__init__.py` in every module, and my package 'successfully' installs with `python -m pip install -e .` I cannot use the submodules.
Below my package:

```
mytestpackage 
   |- python
        setup.py
        |- mytestpackage
                 __init__.py
                |- module1
                    __init__.py
                |- module2
                    __init__.py
        |- notebooks
        |- test
   |- somestuff
   |- README.md
```

I would like to use the sub-modules after import as: `mytestpackage.module1`
However I get an attribute error:

```
AttributeError: module 'mytestpackage' has no attribute 'module1'
```

my setup.py looks like this

```
from setuptools import setup

# Setting up
setup(
    name="mytestpackage",
    version="0.0",
    description="some testing",
    author="me",
    author_email="me@myself.com",
    packages=['mytestpackage', 'mytestpackage.module1', 'mytestpackage.module2'],
    install_requires=[],
)
```

I also tried the standard argument `packages=setoptools.find_packages()` and `packages=setuptools.find_namespace_packages(),` without success.
If I check the installation with conda, I see the package as `<develop>` in my list, and I can also import in python using `import mytestpackage` but as soon as I want to access the submodules with `mytestpackage.module1`, I get an error.
Also, if I run as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73572949/python-package-not-installing-submodules):

```
import pkgutil
import mytestpackage
for i in pkgutil.iter_modules(mytestpackage.__path__):
    print(i)
```

I get

```
ModuleInfo(module_finder=FileFinder('c:\\localdata\\repos\\mytestpackage\\python\\mytestpackage'), name='module1', ispkg=True)
ModuleInfo(module_finder=FileFinder('c:\\localdata\\repos\\mytestpackage\\python\\mytestpackage'), name='module2', ispkg=True)
```

I used to simply add the `__init__.py` files and run the setup.py... Did something changed? Do I have to add an import of the submodules in the  `__init__.py` of `mytestpackage`, i.e. `import mytestpackage.module1`?

Comment: Running into this same problem, I've done this a hundred times, but suddenly this time the submodules can't be found